# Why does my app gets stopped when I click the arithmetic function button in my calculator app?

Tags: java, android, toast

I'm making a calculator app in android studio. Everything works perfect but when the arithmetic button +,-,*,/  is clicked before value1 is entered the app crashes. Even I mentioned that if result(input) is null nothing should take place.

```java
        Button buttonMUL;
        Button buttonDIV;
        Button buttonSUB;
        Button buttonADD;
        Button buttonEQL;


        float value1, value2;
        boolean Add, Mul, Sub, Div;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            buttonADD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result.setText("");
                    }
                    else {
                        value1= Float.parseFloat(result.getText()+"");
                        Op.append("+");
                        result.setText(null);
                        Add = true;


                    }
                }
            });

            buttonMUL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result.setText("");
                    }
                    else {
                        value1= Float.parseFloat(result.getText()+"");
                        Op.append("x");
                        result.setText(null);
                        Mul = true;

                    }
                }
            });

            buttonSUB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result.setText("");
                    }
                    else {
                        value1= Float.parseFloat(result.getText()+"");
                        Op.append("-");
                        result.setText(null);
                        Sub = true;

                    }
                }
            });

            buttonDIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result.setText("");
                    }
                    else {
                        value1= Float.parseFloat(result.getText()+"");
                        Op.append("/");
                        result.setText(null);
                        Div = true;

                    }
                }
            });



            buttonEQL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    value2 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText()+"");
                    Op.setText("");

                    if (Add) {
                        result.setText(value1 + value2+"");
                        Op.setText(result.getText());
                        Add = false;
                    }

                    else if (Mul) {
                        result.setText(value1 * value2+"");
                        Op.setText(result.getText());
                        Mul = false;
                    }
                    else if (Div) {
                        result.setText(value1 / value2+"");
                        Op.setText(result.getText());
                        Div = false;
                    }

                    else if (Sub) {
                        result.setText(value1 - value2+"");
                        Op.setText(result.getText());
                        Sub = false;
                    }

                }
            });

              }
    }
```

Is there any way to prevent it by using some kind of toast or something like that.

Comment: That's too much code. Create a copy of your project and delete everything that is not needed for the problem to reproduce, then come back with the remaining code. We call it a [mcve]

Comment: It's is better if you also post logcat.

Comment: `
                if (result == null) {
                    result.setText("");
                }`

 is going to be wrong.

Comment: Of course, it will crash - if you not entered value1, what can you do with its value?

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize value1 as 0 and handle zero division exception.